# Create flag by unique list in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe called df where i have code and ID columns.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Code':[550, 330, 210, 
                 600, 550, 410, 350, 410],
        'ID':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Code  ID
0   550   1
1   330   2
2   210   3
3   600   4
4   550   5
5   410   6
6   350   7
7   410   8

Now I am trying to create a new column called flag where my condition is :
If any code in [550, 330, 600, 350] then my flag is 1 otherwise 0. But [550, 330, 600, 350] acts as same codes so if any code appear previously then flag is 0 else 1. Same for other codes if any codes other than [550, 330, 600, 350] comes then i will check if that code is present previously then 0 else 1.

In my example first code is 550 and its the first code so flag in 1 as 550 is in [550, 330, 600, 350].
for second code 330 is act as similar code so flag is 0. for third 210 is not present in [550, 330, 600, 350] so flag is 1 as its first appearance. In observation 6 where code is 420 as its a new code so flag is 1 but in observation 8 again 410 come but its already present in the list so flag is 0.

My attempt:

```
fl = []
comman_list = [550, 330, 600, 350]
for i in range(0, len( df['Code'])):
    if df['Code'][i] in comman_list:
        fl.append(1)
    else:
        fl.append(0)
  
df['flag'] = fl
```

Expected output

```
   Code  ID  Flag
0   550   1     1
1   330   2     0
2   210   3     1
3   600   4     0
4   550   5     0
5   410   6     1
6   350   7     0
7   410   8     0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try `replace` first then `duplicated`

```
l= [550, 330, 600, 350]
df['new']=(~df.Code.replace(l,'check').duplicated()).astype(int)
df
Out[409]: 
   Code  ID  new
0   550   1    1
1   330   2    0
2   210   3    1
3   600   4    0
4   550   5    0
5   410   6    1
6   350   7    0
7   410   8    0
```

Comment: How can I do the same using for loop?. As I need to calculate the same using row by row processing.